# encountered an invalid number error calling the below oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT Ticket, ETRs, "Last ETR","Last ETR Time Change","STAR Restore Time","Restore Time - Last ETR"
         FROM(
                SELECT e.xsystemjob Ticket,
                       a.eventkey Event,
                      (select count(generatedtime) from obvwh.ops_ertchangelog_fact where eventkey = a.eventkey) ETRs,
                      to_char(a.ERT, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Last ETR", --GENERATEDTIME,
                      to_char(generatedtime, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Last ETR Time Change",
                      to_char(e.restdate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "STAR Restore Time",
                      round(((e.restdate - a.generatedtime) * 1440),0) as "Restore Time - Last ETR"
                FROM obvwh.ops_ertchangelog_fact a
                join obvwh.ops_event_dim e
                on a.eventkey = e.eventkey
                where a.generatedtime = (select max(generatedtime) from obvwh.ops_ertchangelog_fact where eventkey = a.eventkey)
              )
          WHERE Substr(Ticket,0,1) = region
          AND to_char("Last ETR", 'MM/DD/YYYY') between to_char(start_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_char(end_date,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: This isn't a stored procedure it is just a query. And the error on it is most probably: `to_char("Last ETR", 'MM/DD/YYYY'` or at least one of then.

Comment: Can someone please help...

Comment: This is the query in the SP..

Comment: What are my doing wrong..?

Comment: What is `region` - a number? If so do you have `ticket` values where the first character is not a number? Without the full code and the call to it, and the full error stack showing where the error is being reported, and the table structures, and possibly the data.... kind of hard to tell.

Comment: Does the query run correctly if you copy it from the stored procedure and paste it directly in Toad/SQL Developer/SQL*Plus? You need to figure out first if the error is in the query or in the PL/SQL code. Then, it would help to show the EXACT and COMPLETE error message.

Comment: Also, asking for help every minute will not actually help. SO is not a technical support desk.

Comment: When I run the query without "AND to_char("Last ETR", 'MM/DD/YYYY') between '07/18/2006' and '07/18/2006'" on SQL Developer, it works. Otherwise, I get the invalid number error....

Comment: Try to replace that with `AND "Last ETR" between to_date('07/18/2006', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('07/18/2006', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`. That is at least an improvement (for performance), and may give a more telling error (if any).

Answer (score 0):

From you inner query, `Last ETR` is a string, representing the column value in format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`. You're trying to convert that string to a string, passing a single format mask, and that is throwing the error.

You can see the same thing with a simpler demo:

```
select to_char('07/18/2016 12:13:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

You could explicitly convert the string to a date and back again:

```
select to_char(to_date('07/18/2016 12:13:14', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
07/18/2016
```

... but in the context of your comparison that doesn't really make sense anyway if the range you're comparing with can span a year end - the format mask you're using doesn't allow for simple comparison. Assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are dates (with their times set to midnight) you could do:

```
AND to_date("Last ETR", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') between start_date and end_date;
```

or even simpler, use the original raw `ERT` value (which is presumably already a date), and convert it to a string - if that is actually the right thing to do - in the outermost select list.

I'm not quite sure why you have an inline view here at all though, or why you're using a subquery to get the count since you're already querying `ops_ertchangelog_fact` - maybe you want to be using analytic functions here.